# 'Sprite' object has no attribute 'k'

Tags: python, pygame

My python pygame code isn't working, it's showing

> AttributeError: 'Sprite' object has no attribute 'k'

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

screen_width=1360
screen_height=768
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width,screen_height])

class Sprite:
    def p(self):
        self.s = pygame.Rect(160, 150, 50, 50)
        self.k = pygame.Rect(160, 200, 500, 50)
        return s.colliderect(k)

while True:
    s1 = Sprite()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit(0)
    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if pressed[pygame.K_d]:
        s1.k.x += 1
    if pressed[pygame.K_a]:
        s1.k.x -= 1
    if pressed[pygame.K_w]:
        s1.k.y -= 1
    if pressed[pygame.K_s]:
        s1.k.y += 1
    if s1:
        s1.k.x = 200    

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    square = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 255), s1.k)
    sprite = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (200, 0, 0), s1.s)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

This is my debugger info:

> line 33, in 
>       s1.k.x = 200
>
> AttributeError: 'Sprite' object has no attribute 'k'

Comment: `Sprite` only has the attribute `k` if you call `p` first.

Comment: @CoryMadden when I try to do s1.p.k.x it shows me AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'k'

Comment: `p` is a method. You have to call it as such. `s1.p()` and then `s1.k.x`. But read @Batman's answer. I'm pretty sure that's what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is `p`?

When you create an object in Python, its `__init__` method gets called, which is what defines the properties of the object. You need to define the `k` ans `s` properties inside there.

Something like:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.k = pygame.Rect(160, 200, 500, 50)
    self.s = pygame.Rect(160, 150, 50, 50)
```

Comment: I've modified the answer.

Comment: when I changed p to __init__ it showed me:   
 line 19, in <module>
    s1 = Sprite()

 line 14, in __init__
    return s.colliderect(k)
NameError: name 's' is not defined

Comment: First of all, it should be `__init__`. The double underscores are very important. Secondly, your `__init__` method shouldn't return anything. Finally, in your `p` method, you don't ever define `s`. You probably mean `self.s`

Comment: I did underscores, they didn't show up when I copied them to comment.

Comment: I still don't get it. I need to change p to init, right?

Comment: Not necessarily. You either need to *add* an `__init__` and change your `p` method to `return self.s.colliderect(self.k)`, or rename `p` to `__init__`, and remove the `return` completely.

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said now and application works but now I cannot move it y, because it gets back on its primary position every time I try to move

Comment: @MaksymilianN move the `s1 = Sprite()` above the loop